# Flask - send video frames to flask application live

Tags: opencv, flask

I have a python application that reads video frames (using cv2.VideoCapture) and processes them. I want to send and show ( in a live manner) these processed frames in a dashboard that uses flask server. How do I send these frames from python application to flask server and from flask server to html client. This has to be done in a live manner.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution ?